# How to integrate : $\int \sqrt{\tan^2x +2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate : $\int \sqrt{\tan^2x +2}dx$

Please guide what to substitute or any approach as I am not getting any clue on this , thanks .

Comment: try $u=tan(x)/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: replace tan(x) by 2t then t by cosh(s)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $$\tan x=\sqrt 2\tan\theta \implies \sec^2 x dx=\sqrt 2\sec^2\theta d\theta$$
$$dx=\frac{\sqrt 2\sec^2\theta d\theta}{1+2\tan^2\theta}$$

$$\int \sqrt{\tan^2 x+2} \ dx$$
$$=\int \sqrt{2\tan^2 \theta+2} \frac{\sqrt 2\sec^2\theta d\theta}{1+2\tan^2\theta}$$
$$=\int \sqrt 2 \sec\theta\frac{\sqrt 2\sec^2\theta d\theta}{1+2\tan^2\theta}$$
$$=2\int \frac{\sec^3\theta d\theta}{1+2\tan^2\theta}$$

I hope you can proceed further

Answer (score 1):

By setting $x=\arctan(u\sqrt{2})$ as suggested, then $u=\sinh\theta$, we have:
$$ I = \int\frac{\sqrt{u^2+1}}{u^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,du=\int\frac{\cosh^2\theta}{\sinh^2\theta+\frac{1}{2}}d\theta=\theta+\arctan(\tanh\theta)+C. $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\displaystyle \tan x= \sqrt{2}\tan t\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle dx = \frac{\sqrt{2}dt}{\cos^2 t \cdot (2\tan^2 t+1)} = \frac{\sqrt{2}dt}{\sin^2 t+1}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = 2\int \frac{1}{\cos t}\cdot \frac{1}{\sin^2 t+1} dt = 2\int\frac{\cos t}{(1+\sin^2 t)\cdot (1-\sin^2 t)}dt$$

Now Put $\sin t = u\;,$ Then $\cos t dt = du$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = 2\int\frac{1}{(1-u^2)\cdot (1+u^2)}du = \int \left[\frac{1}{1-u^2}-\frac{1}{1+u^2}\right]du$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right|-\tan^{-1}(u)+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{\tan^2 x+2}+\tan x}{\sqrt{\tan^2x+2}-\tan x}\right|-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{\tan^2 x+2}}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$